# PnPOnline login issue

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-2.0

In our tenants, we use MFA and I needed to use -UseWebLogin if I want to do connect-PNPOnline. The problem I have is when I try to pass my login credentials, it giving me an errors so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion how should I make it work.

I was able to login using just like this but I need to pass my credentials so that I don't have to enter it again and again

```
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
```

If I just use it like this then I got the error below

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials($psCred)

Error: AADSTS53001: Device is not in required device state: domain_joined. Conditional Access policy requires a domain joined device, and the device is not domain joined.
```

So the only solution for me is to use -UseWebLogin like I stated above and I tried like these but I'm still getting an error

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin($psCred) 

or

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin -Credentials($psCred) 

then I got this error
Error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the brackets like that, as if a parameter is like a .net method. Always provide the value after space character, so `-ParamName $value`

Answer (score 0):

You can store your user id and password as object in a variable. Then pass that variable as paramter to -Credential.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).